# Uploading of an Audio file on to the server

Tags: android, http, file-upload

I am trying to send my audio file to the server

```
I am getting response code: 405
and response message : Method not Allowed
```

In my code the socket port is opening.

my code is:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
            DataInputStream inputStream = null;

          //  String pathToOurFile = sourceFileUri;
            String urlServer = "MY SERVER URL";
            String lineEnd = "\r\n";
            String twoHyphens = "--";
            String boundary = "*****";

            int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
            byte[] buffer;
            int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;

            try {
            Log.w("----in try---", " ");

            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(
                    sourceFileUri));

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
            "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream
            .writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\""
            + sourceFileUri + "\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0)
            {
            Log.w("----while (bytesRead > 0)---", " ");

            outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens
            + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();
            Log.i("Test",""+serverResponseCode+"   "+serverResponseMessage);
            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            Log.i("test", " "+ex.getMessage());
            ex.printStackTrace();
            // Exception handling
            }} // end upLoad2Server
```

Can any one help me over this.

UPDATE:

Getting `'File Not Found Exception in server response'`

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21376573/2412041

Comment: @Jack Duong Actually I am getting Method Not Allowed : 405 , in this case if you can help me.

Comment: Please ensure that, your service and client is the same method. (POST)

Comment: @Jack Duong   Is there any authentication required to get access to the server before uploading a file..Otherwise any one can easily upload the file on the server.

Comment: It's up to you. You can use token to accept request from client.